# Getting two ships onto my freighter

Tags: no-mans-sky

I found a crashed starship and added it to my collection, but now I have two starships planet side, and need a way to get to my other one after the new one is on my freighter for repair. Any suggestions?

Comment: How exactly did you "added it to your collection"? I found a crashed ship too but I have no idea how to collect it, maybe to loot it later or to reuse it. How can I see the content of my actual collection?

Comment: PeterCo When you inspect it there should be options to either trade that ship out for your current one, or add it to your collection. But this only works if you have a freighter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The new ship should appear on your freighter by itself. 
I found a new ship after the NEXT update and later found it on my freighter. 
However there may be some problems as my ships are not always present on my freighter and reloading a savegame on the freighter helps sometimes.

Answer (score 2):

I found a crashed ship and repair the engine, i summoned my freighter and entered it with my older ship. Hoped in and out of my ship after I landed in the freighter then simply reloaded my latest  auto save and the crashed freighter was parcked next to mine in my freighter. Now I have 2 ships saved. It needs to be fully repaird to summon and use of course. This is after the "Next" update.